# EF Core with ASP MVC .NET 4.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

In a project I need to set up an ASP.NET MVC (with .NET 4.6.1) but using the "new" EF Core for accessing the database.

Unfortunately every documentation explains only how to setup an ASP.NET **Core** MVC project.

I just gave it a try and when it comes to creating the database via the Package Manager Console I get the error message:

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'DataContext'. Either add a
>   parameterless constructor to 'DataContext' or add an implementation of
>   'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'DataContext'

Yes, I don't have a parameterless constructor but neither does the example code of microsoft

`public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }`

I guess the problem is, that I don't register the DataContext in the Startup.cs which I don't have in an "old" ASP.NET MVC application.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: How are you providing connection string to context in your app?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

A simple example

- **Example.EF** (.NET Standard project with EF Core and Microsoft Dependency Injection).
- **Example.Tools** - *reference Example.EF* (.NET Core CommandLine project to run the migration only for the developer only).
- **Example.MVC** - *reference Example.EF* (MVC5).

In **Example.EF**: Install EF Core, Microsft Dependency Injection. Create a class to support DI

```
public static class IocConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDbContextPool<ExampleContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer("_connectionstring_");
        });

        // Register to support the ExampleController can get DbContext.
        services.AddTransient(typeof(ExampleController));

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new DefaultServiceResolver(serviceProvider));
    }
}

public class DefaultServiceResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DefaultServiceResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

In the **Example.MVC**, with the Application_Start in Global.asax or Startup with Owin

```
// Register services.
IocConfiguration.Configure();

// Example controller
public class ExampleController : Controller 
{
     private readonly ExampleContext _exampleContext;

     public ExampleController(ExampleContext exampleContext)
     {
         _exampleContext = exampleContext;
     }
}
```

To run the migration:

```
Add-Migration {MigrationName} -Project Example.EF -StartupProject Example.Tools
```

We should have IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to support to run the migration.

Comment: There is a way to register all controllers at once?

Comment: @LucianBumb at the _IocConfiguration.Configure()_ we can do simple code with reflection to load all controllers in assembly to register it. Or from your current DI library already support it. Example with **LightInject** [https://www.lightinject.net/mvc/](https://www.lightinject.net/mvc/) just need to call _container.RegisterControllers(typeof(MyMvcApplication).Assembly);_

Answer (score 2):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation, you need to create a factory.

> ## From a design-time factory
>
> You can also tell the tools how to create your DbContext by implementing the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface: If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived `DbContext` or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.
>   C#
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
>
> namespace MyProject
> {
>     public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
>     {
>         public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
>         {
>             var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
>             optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");
>
>             return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Note** The args parameter is currently unused. There is [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8332) tracking the ability to specify design-time arguments from the tools.
>
> A design-time factory can be especially useful if you need to configure the DbContext differently for design time than at run time, if the `DbContext` constructor takes additional parameters are not registered in DI, if you are not using DI at all, or if for some reason you prefer not to have a `BuildWebHost` method in your ASP.NET Core application's
>   `Main` class.

You can't inject a connection string here, but it's not an issue since this is only used for design-time functionality like creating migrations.