# EF Core DataContext with dotNet Framework 4.6.1 and Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core, ninject

I am adding EF Core 2.1.1 to a DotNet Framework 4.6.1 MVC 5 project that is using Ninject for dependency injection. I am would like to create a dbContext using dependency injection. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150727/ef-core-with-asp-mvc-net-4-6) but it only shows how this can be done with the Microsoft dependency injection. I am wondering what the equivalent version of this is in Ninject, especially the part below:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ExampleContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer("_connectionstring_");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ninject, wouldnt it just look something like

```
kernel.Bind<YourDbContextHere>.ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("options", new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContextHere>().UseSqlServer("YourConnectionString").Options);
```

Allows you to set that up and call pretty happily you dbcontexts

Comment: What you have works for ninject but how do I add the options to the context? I get an exception right now: `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.`

Comment: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class YourDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
}

Once you have the dbcontext set up, you shouldnt need override OnConfigure for anything

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. I removed some code from my previous implementation to help validate the ninject context was working and that was the one throwing the error. D'oh. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In a .net Core 2.0 should I add that kernel.Bind<YourDbContextHere>.ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument.......   in startup.cs? or where exactly it needs to be added?

Comment: @JoeSamraj it would be in the startup .cs but it would require some modification - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693305/how-to-integrate-ninject-into-asp-net-core-2-0-web-applications. That question has a detailed answer on how to setup ninject when using .Net Core as it varies depending which version of Ninject you are using

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public MyContext (string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionString);
    }
}

kernel.Bind<MyContext>.ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "YourConnectionString");
```